# Stop interval when empty array

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, rxjs, conversational-ui

I'm receiving a bunch of Messages from serverside and I wanna fake the typing by adding a interval to the pipe.

I'm doing this for now:

```
const stream = interval(1000)
  .pipe(
  map((): Message => {
    return messages.pop();
  })
);

this.feed = merge(
  stream,
  this.local
).pipe(
  scan((acc, x) => [...acc, x], [])
);
```

But I want it to stop the interval once my array 'messages' is empty, could someone help me please? I have been trying to implement .TakeWhile with no success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

takeWhile works fine, you'd need something like this:

```
const stream = interval(1000)   
  .pipe(
     takeWhile(() => messages.length > 0),
     map(() => messages.pop()),   
  );
```

I made a little example on stackblitz, I hope you can work this into your application: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-sq6wxb?file=index.ts

Answer (score 0):

So your problem is that `stream` keeps emitting even after `messages` is empty.

You can use `takeWhile` to complete the stream:

```
const stream = interval(1000).pipe(
  map((): Message => messages.pop()),
  takeWhile(Boolean),
);
```

When `messages` is empty it returns `undefined` which is `false` when turned to boolean so `takeWhile(Boolean)` will complete the stream.